# Docker-compose mounts are going to work with TCP host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I put the docker host in one machine and put the client in other. Then I try to run some like this from machine 2 (client).

```
docker -H tcp://machine1:port run -v ./dummy-folder:/dummy-folder alpine sh
```

Is that dummy-folder going to work through TCP connection?
Is the same valid for docker-compose too?
is the same valid for docker swarm mode?

Answer (score 1):

The volume mount will run locally on the docker host where the container runs, there's no path over the TCP connection for the volume mount (there is a build time packaging of the build context to send that from the client to the server). Swarm is unchanged, if you mount a volume, it will mount on whatever host the container happens to run on.

If you can't replicate your data across the hosts, then you'll want to use a volume mount over the network to a shared storage location or use a volume driver that does the replication for you (e.g. nfs, infinite, glusterfs, flocker).

Comment: Is there still not an option for this use case? I wanted to mount a folder from macos  to a docker container running in oracle cloud.

Comment: Not that I've seen. You either need to upload your data, or configure your external container host with a mount command back to your client (which would be very unusual). It's probably easiest to put the data on an NFS share and mount that from both your docker server and client.